# In FastApi how can I pass a dictionary as a query parameter for a get request

Tags: fastapi

so say if I had a dictionary {"userId":"bob","password":"12345"} how can I pass that as a query paramater in a get request in fastapi. I know I can use the Requests class but that returns it as a string not a dictionary.

Comment: I hope this is just an example and you're not trying to pass user/pass info through a standard requests. It's not secure.

Comment: yeah just an example

Answer (score 1):

If you define a parameter with type `Request`, you can use it's members as you like. The following would return your requirement. It will run as-is, you can run it immediately.

EDIT: The question was around passing a dict into an API. You can't do that with query parameters (which can only be simple types) but you can use a POST endpoint that accepts an arbitrary dictionary. See the below test.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test_with_arbitrary_query_params")
async def root(request: Request):
    return request.query_params._dict

@app.post("/test_with_dict")
async def root2(input: dict[str, str] = None):
    return input
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Using curl:

```
curl -X GET localhost:8000/test_with_arbitrary_query_params -G -d 'userId=usr' -d 'password=pwd'
```

results in `{"userId":"usr","password":"pwd"}`.

The endpoint that accepts a dict, can be tried from either the automated docs, or also with curl:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8000/test_with_dict  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"userId":"usr","password":"pwd"}'
```

Response: `{"userId":"usr","password":"pwd"}`

Comment: thing is here we are passing strings I actually wanna pass a dictionary

Comment: can you provide a URL example? `Dict`s are a python concept, I don't see how (or why) you are passing those via an url.

Comment: cause I don't have a fixed amount of values that I will be passing such as here. Like here I have 2 values passing but I can end up having 3 values passing or 4 values passing. and all of these are in the format of key and values so that's why I need a dictionary cause I can't just hardcode the amount of query params cause it changes.

Comment: That is perfectly possible, but I would use a POST endpoint and a body for that.. I'll adjust the example.

Comment: thing is I'm retreiving information from the database so shouldn't I use "get" with a body. cause wouldn't I use post when I am adding to the database

Comment: Well that is semantics I'd reckon. If you are hell bent on using a GET, then you need unspecified query parameters and read them from the `Request` object.  I have finalised my answer.

Comment: can you show an example of that

Comment: I have updated my answer, is this not what you need?

Answer (score -2):

Using multiple body parameters (in the dict form you're looking for) can be used [like this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#multiple-body-parameters) from FastAPI docs.